# accumulated or remove decimal with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to accumulated or remove decimal with jquery

**HTML :**

```
<button>Run</button>

<p>
  <span class='aaa'>333</span> 
  <span class='bbb'></span>  
</p>
```

**jQuery :**

```
// jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var aaa = $(".aaa").html();
        var bbb = aaa * 12/100;
        $(".bbb").html(bbb);
    });         
});
```

**Thank you in advance**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
  var aaa = $(".aaa").html();
  var bbb = aaa * 12/100;
  $(".bbb").html(bbb);
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Run</button>

<p>
  <span class='aaa'>333</span> 
  <span class='bbb'></span>  
</p>
```

Comment: What result are you expecting? What have you tried?

Comment: *"How to accumulated or remove decimal"* - That doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "accumulated"?

Comment: i want , example **39.96** to **40** or **39.40**  to  **39**

Comment: That's called "rounding to the nearest integer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(Math.round(39.96));
console.log(Math.round(39.40));
```

```js
// jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var aaa = $(".aaa").html();
        var bbb = Math.round(aaa * 12/100);
        $(".bbb").html(bbb);
    });         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Run</button>

<p>
  <span class='aaa'>333</span> 
  <span class='bbb'></span>  
</p>
```

Comment: **thank you very much**, you have helped me, for my college assignments